# How does PIP determine the version of a dependency of multiple dependents

Tags: python, pip, package, dependency-management, package-managers

Let's assume we have the following dependency tree in Python using [PIP](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip) as package installer:

```
A==1.2.1:
|  - B==1.5.4
|  - C==?.?.?

D==1.3.0:
|  - C==?.?.?
```

Let's also assume that the existing versions of package `C` are the followings:

```
- 0.0.8
- 1.0.2
```

As we know, [PIP](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip) will not install different versions of the same package into an environment. Which means it has to pick one suitable version for all dependents.

What I simply cannot understand how PIP determines the suitable version.

If package `A` depends on `C==0.0.8` and package `D` depends on `C==1.0.2`, this situation cannot get easily handled, unlike other package managers such as [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) could do.

Comment: In that case `pip` should report an error, as it cannot satisfy both dependencies at the same time. Did you check this with some example projects?

Comment: I wonder how does `npm` resolves contradicting dependencies? I think it's simply not possible. Or maybe `npm` installs multiple versions of a dependency to be used by different consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When pip installs a package, it automatically installs any dependent Python packages without checking if these conflict with previously installed packages. It will install a package and any of its dependencies regardless of the state of the existing installation. Because of this, a user with a working installation of, for example, Google Tensorflow, can find that it stops working having used pip to install a different package that requires a different version of the dependent NumPy library than the one used by Tensorflow. In some cases, the package may appear to work but produce different results in detail.*

[Anaconda (Python distribution) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution))

Answer (score 0):

On this topic, things will change relatively soon. Since *pip*'s developers are currently working on a new *dependency resolver*:

- https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2020/03/new-pip-resolver-to-roll-out-this-year.html

---

To test it today, you might want to install *pip 20.2b1* and enable the *unstable feature* "*resolver*", with for example either one of the following:

- `PIP_UNSTABLE_FEATURE=resolver python -m pip install SomeProject`
- `python -m pip --unstable-feature=resolver install SomeProject`

See the following link for more details:

- https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-2b1-release/4242

---

Other references:

- http://www.ei8fdb.org/thoughts/2020/05/test-pips-alpha-resolver-and-help-us-document-dependency-conflicts/
- https://pradyunsg.me/blog/2020/03/27/pip-resolver-testing/
- https://www.pythonpodcast.com/pip-resolver-dependency-management-episode-264/

---

**Update** *pip 20.2*

- https://pythoninsider.blogspot.com/2020/07/upgrade-pip-20-2-changes-20-3.html