# Version conflicts for Python apps but not for interactive development

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pkg-resources

I have a package `P` that depends on a package `A`. Package `A` depends on packages `B` and `C==3`. At the same time, Package `B` depends on `C==4`.

This creates conflicts and an akward error message is shown in red every time I pip install packages `P` or `A`.

Now, I know I can run packages `P` and `A` just fine if I import them in an interactive terminal or Jupyter notebook and I call the functions and classes I need. However, package `P` has a command line application, which raises an error as long as you have the install conflicts inherited from package `A`.

This error is not raised by me, it is raised by the Python interpreter alone (I think), since I am not calling any new functionality compared to when I use `P` as a library. In fact, my CLI is a class wrapped by `fire`, which I can call without problems in an interactive session.

The error trace shows `pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict` in the end, which I never call in `P`.

Given that I can only control what happens in package `P`, is there a way for make it work directly as a command line app?

I am also interested to know what is happening under the hood.

Bytheway, I am always installing  `P` in a new Conda environment.

For package `B` there is only one version available, not multiple versions.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I understanding it right that the dependencies of `A` contradict themselves? Is `A` a public project? I would be interested to see this more in details.

Comment: `A` is not a public project, but out of my scope. The dependencies of `A` do not contradict, but have a conflict with the dependencies of `B`. The conflict is only evident for a couple of functions that one may decide not to use.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood the version of *B* is not constrained by *A*, so basically any version of *B* would be acceptable. Now, maybe there is a version of *B* that has `C==3` in its dependencies. If such a version of *B* exists, let's say it's `B==5`, then the following could work:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install P B==5
```

If it does indeed work, for a long term solution, you might want to try one of the following:

- Set a `B==5` constraint on your project *P*, since you have control over it. I probably wouldn't recommend it though, since *B* is not actually a direct dependency of *P*.
- Use a [`constraints.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) containing `B==5` and call *pip* with the [`--constraint` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-constraint):

  - `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --constraint constraints.txt P`

---

Additionnally I would recommend giving *pip*'s new, experimental dependency resolver a try. It might be better at finding the right combination or projects to install in such situations.

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip --unstable-feature=resolver install P
```

See this answer for details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872812/11138259

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that there is only one possible version of dependency `B`

Comment: Then `A` could never ever work to begin with, could it. The whole thing doesn't make any sense, or I am missing something entirely. -- If we exclude `P` from the equation, is there a version of `A` with its dependencies that has no conflict?

Comment: @sinroc `A` always have that conflict, but that does not mean `A` does not work. As I said, everything works if I use a Python interactive session but not if I run the script from the command line.