# Pip installs unnecessarily conflicting dependencies for a library built with Poetry

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

I've specified the dependencies of a library using Poetry and `^` version constraints. The dependencies conflict if you just install the latest version of the dependencies, but they are resolvable and `poetry install` correctly resolves them. However, `pip install` from `pyproject.toml` does not correctly resolve them and creates a conflict.

**Minimal example**

directory structure:

```
poetry_poc/
poetry_poc/__init__.py
pyproject.toml
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty and the contents of `pyproject.toml` are:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "poetry_poc"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "minimal example of issue"
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
requests = "^2.18.4"
snowflake-connector-python = "^2.2.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

The constraint `snowflake-connector-python = "^2.2.9"` is only resolvable with version 2.2.9, so that gets installed. That library then [requires](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/v2.2.9/setup.py#L176) `requests<2.24.0`, and my project specifies `requests^2.18.4`, so any version between 2.18.4 and 2.23.x would work just fine, but instead pip installs requests 2.24.0 and reports:

```
ERROR: snowflake-connector-python 2.2.9 has requirement requests<2.24.0, but you'll have requests 2.24.0 which is incompatible.
```

I've tried this on a brand new virtual environment with nothing but pip 20.1.1 and setuptools 39.0.1 installed, and I run `pip install . --no-cache-dir` so every dependency will be downloaded anew. My poetry version is 1.0.10.

Is this the expected behavior—that pip won't resolve these types of conflicts—or am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Give _pip_'s new dependency resolution a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872812/11138259

Comment: @sinoroc that works!! though i'm a little loathe to require my end-users install a prerelease version of pip and use the unstable feature flag. 

was i mistaken in assuming that pip would resolve this in its current version?

Comment: Understandable. There is another thing to take into account: as far as I understood, _poetry_ uses non standard version specifiers (I don't know if "standard" is the right word here). In this case `^` is not part of [_PEP 440_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) (which is more or less the standard specification). So that may (not sure, just a guess) have also introduced some extra complication. Maybe it would be interesting to show what was indeed written in the distribution's metadata. Maybe post the content of the `METADATA` file from the wheel.

Comment: Building the wheel with `poetry build` and inspecting it with the `wheel_inspect` lib, i see that it's correctly translated the `^` into requests `<3.0.0,>=2.18.4` and snowflake `<3.0.0,>=2.2.9`, so seemingly there is no issue there. (Additionally, switching to `>=` in pyproject gives the same result as in the original post.)

Comment: Good. It was worth checking, to exclude _poetry_'s version specifier as potential cause. -- I would tell you to file an issue on _pip_'s bug tracker, but since it seems to be fixed in the (soon to be released?) new dependency solver I am not sure it would get attention. Might be worth filing the bug anyway, maybe you would get a different suggestion over there. -- Still I am bit surprised the current versions of _pip_ can't solve this, as it's not really a difficult one. -- I wouldn't worry too much about your end-users, it's out of your hands, just add a prominent note in your documentation.